# correlation in matlab

Tags: matlab, correlation

The following script finds the correlation between each pair of data.

```
clear all
LName={'Name1','Name2','Name3','Name4','Name5'};
Data={rand(12,1),rand(12,1),rand(12,1),rand(12,1),rand(12,1)};
%place in a structure
d = [LName;Data];
Data = struct(d{:});

d1 = cell2mat(struct2cell(Data)');
[R,P] = corrcoef(d1);
Correlation = [LName(nchoosek(1:length(R),2)) num2cell(nonzeros(tril(R,-1)))]
```

Furthermore, the script also states in 'Correlation' which combination of data was used in generating the correlation value. From this I am attempting to not only find the correlation between a pair of data but also find the correlation between n number of data, so in addition to the script above I'm trying to find the correlation between 3 sets of data, and then four... and so on, then store this in Correlation. How would I acheive this?

Comment: Do you need the correlations at multiple offsets, or do you just need the zero offset (i.e. no offset) correlation?

Comment: You might also want to improve your "accept" percentage if you want people to help you.

Comment: Well, the code above calculates the correlation between Name1,Name2; Name1,Name3; Name1,Name4; Name1,Name5 and so on, what I'm trying to do is as well as doing this I want to calculate the correlation between Name1,Name2,Name3;... and so on. Then store all of the values and the headings in 'Correlation'.

Comment: "I'm trying to find the correlation between 3 sets of data, and then four... and so on". There is no such thing as correlation between 3 or more sets of data.  You compute correlations between pairs of data sets. Each pair then results in an entry in the correlation matrix.

Answer (score -1):

Since your numbers are all non-negative I think simply multiplying the relevant arrays together, summing, and normalizing would be sufficient.  This is basically the same thing that corrcoef does, except it only multiplies two arrays together at a time.

Please note, though, that this wouldn't work for negative numbers.  For instance, imagine that all three arrays have a negative value at some point.  This would be good, in the sense that they are well correlated.  Simply multiplying them, though, would give you a negative correlation, which would indicate opposite correlation at that point.

Comment: Your description of what correlation is and how it works is misleading. Negative correlation does not mean bad correlation. In fact, -1 means perfect correlation, but in opposing directions as you would get from two data sets x,y related by the relation y=-x.