# Table of correlation values

Tags: matlab, correlation

If you run the following code you will end up with a cell array composed of a correlation value in `CovMatrix(:,3)` and the name of the data used in calculating the correlation in `CovMatrix(:,1)` and `CovMatrix(:,2)`:

```
clear all
FieldName = {'Name1','Name2','Name3','Name4','Name5'};
Data={rand(12,1),rand(12,1),rand(12,1),rand(12,1),rand(12,1)};
DataCell = [FieldName;Data];%place in a structure - this is the same
%structure that the data for the lakes will be placed in.
DataStructure = struct(DataCell{:});
FieldName = fieldnames(DataStructure); 
Combinations = nchoosek (1:numel(FieldName),2);
d1 = cell2mat(struct2cell(DataStructure)');%this will be the surface temperatures
%use the combinations found in 'Combinations' to define which elements to
%use in calculating the coherence.
R = cell(1,size(Combinations,1));%pre-allocate the cell array
Names1 = cell(1,size(Combinations,1));
for j = 1:size(Combinations,1);
    [R{j},P{j}] = corrcoef([d1(:,[Combinations(j,1)]),d1(:,[Combinations(j,2)])]);
    Names1{j} = ([FieldName([Combinations(j,1)],1),FieldName([Combinations(j,2)],1)]);
end
%only obtain a single value for the correlation and p-value
for i = 1:size(Combinations,1);
    R{1,i} = R{1,i}(1,2);
    P{1,i} = P{1,i}(1,2);
end
R = R';P = P';
%COVARIANCE MATRIX
CovMatrix=cell(size(Combinations,1),3);%pre-allocate memory
 for i=1:size(Combinations,1);
     CovMatrix{i,3}=R{i,1};
     CovMatrix{i,1}=Names1{1,i}{1,1};
     CovMatrix{i,2}=Names1{1,i}{1,2};
 end
```

From this I need to produce a table of the values, preferably in the form of a correlation matrix, similar to [jeremytheadventurer.blogspot.com](http://jeremytheadventurer.blogspot.com/2011/04/correlation-matrix.html). Would this be possible in MATLAB?

Comment: Seems like a repeat of your previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851290/correlation-in-matlab). The reason you didn't get good answers is probably because your question is not clear and your code example is more complicated than it should.

Comment: Dont see how it can't be clear, the code is just an example code which just produces an outcome, the structure of the code is irrelevant. Was simply just asking if it was possible to get from the outcome 'CovMatrix' to the table shown in the link. Complicated?

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the correlation matrix of your entire data set in one shot using `corrcoef` command:

```
% d1 can be simply computed as
d1_new = cell2mat(Data);

% Make sure that d1_new is the same matrix as d1
max(abs(d1(:)-d1_new(:)))

% Compute correlation matrix of columns of data in d1_new in one shot
CovMat = corrcoef(d1_new)

% Make sure that entries in CovMat are equivalent to the third column of
% CovMatrix, e.g.
CovMat(1,2)-CovMatrix{1,3}
CovMat(1,4)-CovMatrix{3,3}
CovMat(3,4)-CovMatrix{8,3}
CovMat(4,5)-CovMatrix{10,3}
```

Because the correlation matrix `CovMat` is symmetric, this contains the required result if you ignore the upper triangular part.

Comment: And if you want it to be zero you can do:
tril(CovMat,0)